# How to obtain flash scope - Play Framework with Scala, maximum arguments in template

Tags: scala, playframework, message

I read book play with scala written in 2013 and I have already found some problems with the latest play version. One of them was i18n Messages, which I successfully solved. But now I meet another problem, which is:

Author explains flash scope. And in the example in the book there is something like:
(inside main.scala.html template)

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit flash: Flash)
```

But in my code it must be:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit messages: Messages)(implicit flash: Flash)
```

And here's the problem. When I add **(implicit flash: Flash)** I recieve an error by my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) which is: **"wrong top statement declaration"**

I suppose that template has its maximum number of parameters (templates are functions as far as I know) so I cant add one more. The question is how to obtain flash scope object?

Please explain to me the idea of these parameters. Thanks!

Comment: There can be only one implicit parameter list in a function like this:  @(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit messages: Messages, flash: Flash)

Comment: @grotrianster will you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be only one implicit parameter list in a function and must be the last one, like this: `@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit messages: Messages, flash: Flash)`

Comment: I noticed that I get an error: could not find implicit value for parameter flash play.api.mvc.Flash  whats my mistake?

Comment: Most likely your Action is missing implicit request,  Action {implicit request => Ok(...)}

Comment: i have found that answer on playframework.com but it doesn't help, I have implicit request => everywhere in my controllers and it still doesnt work